Laravel scheduler killed on container
I have created a docker container with a cron job, the cronjob runs php artisan schedule:run command every minute, but after a while of execution times the command return "Killed", It remains like this until the container restarts.
I thought it was a memory problem, so I placed the value -1 in Memory_limit in the php.ini
But it didn´t work...
What else may cause this behavior?

Have you checked the max_execution_time ini setting?

Yes, I also tried setting it to Unlimited, but the error still appears., also when I enter to the container and manually execute php artisan the error appears.

There are numerous reasons why the process could be killed off; without more information, it's impossible to pinpoint exactly why. Take a look at using 'Supervisor' to manage the process instead of cron. 'Supervisor' ensures that the command runs reliably, restarts it if it’s killed, and handles logging, which makes troubleshooting easier.
Dockerfile
RUN apt update && apt install -y supervisor
COPY ./supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]

Supervisor Configuration
Create a Supervisor configuration file named supervisord.conf:
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:laravel-scheduler]
command=php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:work --verbose --no-interaction
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/storage/logs/scheduler.log

